# Unable to show new properties in User schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema, meanjs

I'm working within a MEAN app, and I'm modifying the User module. I modified the User Schema to contain 2 new properties: casetype and Steps. casetype is just a string, and Steps is an array. I created a view to show these along with a controller. Neither are shown on the page when I run the server. If I try to show any of the preexisting properties of the logged in user, they work fine, it just seems to be the new stuff I added that doesn't work. What's more puzzling is that they save just fine to the database, and when using Mongo shell I can find the user by querying based on casetype.

view:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 ng-bind="vm.user.casetype"></h1> 
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="tableWrapper">
        <table id = "table_id" class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Step</th>
              <th>Todo</th>
              <th>Completed?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="step in vm.user.steps.type | filter: query" >
              <td>{{step.num}}</td>
              <td>{{step.text}}</td>
              <td class = "y_n">{{step.completed}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UserSchema additions:

```
//case type
casetype: {
  type: String,
  default: 'Default Case Type'
},
//steps for case tracking
steps: {
  type: [{
    num: {
      type: Number,
      //default: 0
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      //default: 'Todo for step'
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      //default: false
    }
  }],
  default: [{
    num: 0,
    text: 'todo for step',
    completed: false
  }]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps is an object. you need to render steps.type which is an array:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in vm.user.steps.type | filter: query" >
        <td>{{t.num}}</td>
        <td>{{t.text}}</td>
        <td class = "y_n">{{t.completed}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for this fix, but this still doesn't solve the root issue, it still does not show up in the view.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in double curly braces like so- `<h1>{{vm.user.casetype}}</h1>`

Comment: Also what is query? if it's null, it will try to match filter with null value which might be the cause. Try removing the filter to begin with.

Comment: I've tried using double curly braces, and that didn't work either, and removing the filter has no effect. I'm pretty sure the issue is not in the view itself